# Team Foundation Server Continuous Integration on same machine as developer

Tags: continuous-integration

Will it be slow if I set this up?

I have both running on my machine and I wanted to setup CI with TFS 2010. So everytime I check in code it sets off a build. Will this make the process of coding while building make my computer really slow?

I just want to test everything else before investing in a separate machine for the builds and stuff.

Comment: Consider a VM instead of buying a full machine.  The build machine will be doing literally nothing most of the time.

Comment: @Marcie - Our build machine is active throughout the day with very frequent Continuous Integration builds.  That being said, be careful with the idea of a VM, as compiling can use a lot of burst CPU and require a decent amount of memory.  Skimping on these will slow things down considerably.

Comment: I'm imagining there are not a lot of developers in this environment since the OP is talking about running it on his/her own machine.  I could be wrong though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be slow. Especially if your machine will build when others check in too. If you are the only one making commits, it'll probably be just about bearable.

Comment: I'll be the only one making commits, so would it be okay?

Answer (score 5):

Slow yes, and from a build quality point of view, I'd be concerned. Developer machines (mine included) have all sorts of ugly things installed on them, and hacks to make things work. I'm a really big fan of having a dedicated build machine (virtual or real).

Comment: I will be setting something like that up hopefully, but for now I only have one machine. If I setup a laptop as the build machine, like a netbook, would that be okay?

Comment: As a temporary solution, using your own box is fine - it will slow things down, but how often do you commit? How big is your build? It shouldn't be too tragic. The netbook would be ok, but you'd probably have slower builds (but not slowing your machine). Either strategy is fine as a temp solution.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages that a build server brings is preventing the "works fine on my box" arguments. So I'd consider using VM in the first phase to show the benefits of CI to the executives. Then claiming a dedicated server for builds will be easier.